# Is ${ \lim_{n\to\infty} } A_n= \left\{ \frac{k}{n},0 \le k \le n\right\} = \left[ 0,1 \right] $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

So this might seem like a strange, elementary question, but a problem I'm working on has lead me to a tangent problem.

If : $A_n = \left\{ \frac{k}{n},0 \le k \le n \right\}$, then is

$\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n = \left[ 0,1 \right] $?

Intuitively, I would say yes, since, as $n$ approches infinity, the interval $\left[ {0,1} \right]$ is split into more and more, smaller and smaller pieces.
This also seem to me to be, like, the fundamental principle of integration, where you cut up the area under of a function into infintesimally small slices.

However, I've never seen this idea written like this.

What's more,when $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, ${A_n}$ only contains rational numbers, so is this property conserved as $n \to + \infty$?

I'm pretty lost, as I don't really know how to handle a sequence of sets, and Google and SearchOnMath searches haven't given any good answers.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of $\lim A_n$?

Comment: With the usual definition of $\lim A_n$ (used in Probability Theory, for example) every point of $\lim A_n$ is a rational number.

Comment: Which would mean ${A_n}$ doesn't converge to [0 ; 1] ? I might be saying nonsense, but as n approaches infinity, aren't you going to have i for every n, ${0 \le i \le n}$ such that  : ${ k_i \le \frac{ \pi }{10} \le k_{i+1}}$ , with ${ k_i = \frac{i}{n} }$ . In this sense, these two numbers are closer and closer upper and lower bounds on ${  \frac{ \pi }{10}}$, an irrational numer ?

Comment: There is no single, canonical way of defining the limit of sequence of sets, so the answer depends on which definition of limit is used. For instance, the answer is yes if you are using the [Hausdorff metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). On the other hand, when the limit is considered using the lattice structure on the power set of $[0, 1]$, the limit does not exist because $\limsup A_n=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ while $\liminf A_n=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Reading the other comments, it seems that OP has fallen into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This also highlights the importance of providing the context!

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that there are different possible [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit) for a limit of a sequence of sets. In this case, the limit infimum is the empty set and the limit supremum is all the rationals in $[0,1]$. For the limit infimum consider $A_n \cap A_{n+1} = \{0,1\}$ for $n > 1$ and for the limit supremum consider that $A_n \subset A_{nk}$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and that the rational $a/b$ will be in $A_b$, so it will be in the union.

The problem here is that you could have in your head another definition of sets, or maybe these definitions don't work for the original problem that originated this one. In that case, you should explicitly say what's the purpose of this tangent problem. With the usual definitions, we would say that the infimum is different to the supremum so the limit, by itself, would be undefined. Maybe the union is what interests you, but then it's trivial that irrationals won't ever be in the union, because all $A_n$ have only rationals.

Comment: The original problem is :

Given a continuous function ${ f : [0 ; 1] \to \mathbb{R}   }$ , show that the sequence defined by :

${ (U_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} ^*} }$ : ${U_n = }$ ${ max }${ ${ f( \frac{k}{n}) , 0 \le k \le n }$ }   converges.

I initially wanted to show that ${U_n}$ converges to ${ \sup_{x \in [0 ; 1]} f(x) }$

From there, I wanted to show that { ${ f( \frac{k}{n}) , 0 \le k \le n }$ } converges to ${ f([0 ; 1]) }$ .

And from there, I came to my original question. I'm pretty sure this is just a simple real analysis problem, so I might be overthinking this.

Comment: @Eli It's okay to overthink problems, it lets you learn new things. Call $B = [0,1]$, imagine that my answer here would have been "It's true that $A_n$ converges to B". Then what? You actually want to prove that then the maximum of $f$ in $A_n$ converges to the supremum $B$. The essential problem for that is that the limits with sets are tools for set-theory questions. Continuity and limits of functions have an additional feature, you care about how close numbers are, which set-theory doesn't help you with, it can't help. It's important to learn that set-theory tools can't directly help here!

Comment: @Eli Not to say that what you had in mind is impossible to formalize, it's just that I think you would need topology concepts like density, closure and compacity. So it gets harder than what I assume you want to use. If I were you, I would start a different proof with $\epsilon-\delta$ and using that $f$ has a maximum in its domain.